# How can I execute jQuery within a *Basic page* content type node?

Tags: javascript

I would like to run some jquery within a *Basic page* content type node and the only place that I can place this code is within the Body section when within the *Edit Basic page*.
After placing the following at the bottom of the Body section like the below:
jQuery(window).unload( function () { alert("Bye now!"); } );

It errors off so that it appears that it does not have jQuery included within this content type.
I tried putting a link to Jquery before calling jQuery but the link to it also errors off.
How can I execute jQuery within a *Basic page* content type node?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but You can try to change filter to Full HTML, or the second method, create template file for that content type like node--NAMEOFNODETYPE.tpl.php and clear cache and put your javascript code inside it.

example:

```
<div>
     // Here YOUR JAVASCRIPT CODE
     <?php print render($content['body']); ?>
</div>
```

Or another method, in template_preprocces_page you can check: for all nodes by one type - just check:

```
$node = menu_get_object();
if($node->type == "your type") {
  drupal_add_js('YOUR CODE', 'inline');
}
```

for only one node by nid:

```
$node = menu_get_object();
if($node->nid == YOUR NID) {
  drupal_add_js('YOUR CODE', 'inline');
}
```